# Prompt user for values for all public properties on a class

Tags: c#, reflection

C# makes it relatively easy to [get all public properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.8) , or [get a property value by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp).

But what about *setting* property values? For a simple test application I would like to be able to do something like this pseudocode which enumerates public properties on a class instance, prompts the user for values, and sets the properties based on these values - converting from input strings to property types as needed:

```
for(Property p in typeof(instance))
{
 s = ReadLine("Enter the value for {p.Name}, type {p.Type}");
 SetPropertyValue(instance,p.Name, p.Type.parse(s));
}
```

The major issue I come across that makes a general utility method `SetPropertyValue` difficult is that `Parse` doesn't always exist. It does on most basic types but not for `string` of course or for higher-level types.

I don't mind if it fails on types it doesn't support because my use would basically be `int`,`short`,`string`, `byte`, etc but how can I employ reflection to knock something up for console mode test apps?

Comment: You can probably solve this by using [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter) and `TypeDescriptor`. Maybe the `System.Convert` can be useful here as well.

Answer (score 1):

@Mr. Boy - something along these lines?:

```
    ...
    public class Class1
    {
            public int IntProperty { get; set; }
            public string StringProperty { get; set; }
    }
    ...
    var instance1 = new Class1();
    var typeofclass1 = typeof(Class1);
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] listProperty = instance1.GetType().GetProperties();
    var somevalue = "1234";
    foreach(var p in listProperty)
    {
            p.SetValue(instance1, Convert.ChangeType(somevalue, p.PropertyType), null);
    }
```

Comment: `typeofproperty` seems to be misnamed.

Comment: @NetMage - why? compiles for me just fine.

Comment: Because `typeofproperty` is in fact exactly what the variable __is not__. It is a `PropertyInfo` for the `p.Name` property of `Class1`, so perhaps `propertyInfoForName` or `piFromClass1` would be much better.

Comment: I started to edit and found a second issue - you have `p` already - why are you looking it up again? Just use `p`.